# Owl - Caurusel в angular6

Tags: angular2, angular

Не работает owl-carousel когда перебираю данные циклом *ngFor, скорее всего это происходит из-за того что скрипт owl-carousel запускается раньше чем срабатывает get метод.  Как можно исправить эту последовательность? или как можно сделать по другому? Спасибо.

Comment: Было бы здорово добавить ваш код в вопрос

Comment: какой get метод? какой скрипт owl-carousel? owl-carousel настраивается вручную, к тому же уже давно есть пакет `ngx-owl-carousel`, который как раз таки предназначен для интеграции с angular